# Determine degree of a field extension with degree 8

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, extension-field

I am trying to determine the degree of the field extension $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i)$. For this I use the following:

$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3}):\mathbb{Q}]$.

First I determine: $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3}):\mathbb{Q}] = 4$ (I think I know the reason)

Then I try to determine: $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})]$

$i \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i)$ is the root of $x^2+1 \in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})[X]$

And $x^2+1$ is the minimal polynomial, because $i\notin\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$.

=> $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})] \leq 2$

So I claim:  $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})] = 1$

It follows  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$, coz $i \in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})\subset\mathbb{R}$

=> $i \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$

=> $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i) \neq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$

=> $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})] \neq 1$

Is this correct?
How to argue $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})] > 2$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you have to argue that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})] > 2$? You know that it is $\leq 2$ ($i$ satisfies $x^{2} + 1 = 0$) and you have established that it is $\ne 1$ so it is $=2$. A side note: Include the whole expressions in the dollar signs, there is no need to leave out a bracket "[" or a number such as "2" (which you did in the last expression)

Comment: I made a mistake I mean [$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})]\not>$2. But I do not have to prove that?

Comment: Yes you have to prove it, but you have already done that by noticing that: since $X^2 +1 \in \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[4]{3})[X] $ the degree of the extension by $i$ cannot be larger than $2$ (which is in your post).

Comment: Remember that if $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$ and satisfy a polynomial equation $p_{n}(x) = 0$ where $p_{n}(x)\in F[x]$ and the degree of $p_{n}$ is $n$ then $[F(\alpha): F]\leq n$